# Does Microsoft Visual Studio Express C++ 2010 have installer maker capability?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, installation

I've only started to play around with Visual Studio Express C++ 2010 (more comfortable with Autotools on *nix platforms) and am still exploring the menu items, but I'd like to just get the answer from someone who knows whether or not with the free version one can make .msi installers for their programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you are [out of luck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx) :

> The Express Editions do not include Windows Installer technology

However, you should be able to get this capability for free via the [Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Good luck - post new qs if you get stuck!